# After giving input show div for sometime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where i need to show a div when a user provides input.

When a user continuously changes the input value the div must be shown and when the user stops providing input after 5 secs or so the div must be hidden.

Ctrl :

```
    function MainCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.appear = false;
  $scope.showDiv = function() {
    debugger;
    $scope.appear = true;
  }
  $scope.$watch('appear',
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if(newValue && newValue===true){
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.appear=false;
        }, 5000);

     } 
    }
  );
}
```

html:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Name: <input type="text" ng-change="showDiv()" ng-model="inputText"/> <br/>

  <div ng-show="appear">Content</div>
</body>
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/H6DJQqgSY3COruGrO5M4?p=preview)

The issue i am facing here is when i continuously provide input the div at some point of time it is getting hidden and reappearing again.

But I need the div to be shown till the input is being provided and when a user stops providing any input after 5 secs it should disappear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes to your plunkr, check this link https://plnkr.co/edit/EsiG3Ifgk0maYF4GJTGm?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.appear = false;

    $scope.timerId;
    $scope.showDiv = function() {

        if($scope.timerId!=undefined){
        clearTimeout($scope.timerId);
    }
    $scope.appear = true;
    $scope.timerId = $timeout(function(){
       $scope.appear=false;
    },5000);  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should clear your timeout: https://plnkr.co/edit/wY4C1wvBZKJ7RSwtgnCv?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

function MainCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
  var timeout;
  $scope.appear = false;
  $scope.showDiv = function() {
    // debugger;
    $scope.appear = true;

    if(timeout) {
      console.log('timeout')
      $timeout.cancel(timeout); 
    }

    timeout = $timeout(function(){
      $scope.appear=false;
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got below code working :

```
$scope.showDiv = function () {
    alert(1);
    $('#divShow').show();
    setTimeout("$('#divShow').hide();", 5000);
}
```

Write this in the controller and give that `"divShow"` id to div and remove ng-show thing.

This worked for me, Hope help you.